# How do I align the following label and check box in rails slim file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim

```
= simple_form_for [:manage, @program] do |f|
  = f.input :page_declined_path
  = f.label :customize_terms
  = f.check_box :customize_terms
```

I want to align customize terms and the respective checkbox as follows
[similar alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stJ3J.png)

Comment: I think you need to add css for the same

Comment: If you're using something like Bootstrap, i would suggest to split every label and input of your form manually and place them in the desired layout using the bootstrap grid (or equivalent). If you're not using a css framework then you can also split your labels and input into divs and customize them with css manually as well